# The incircle of a triangle $ABC$ touches $AB$ at point $P$ and has radius equal to $21$.If $AP=23$ and $PB=27$

Tags: geometry

The incircle of a triangle $ABC$ touches $AB$ at point $P$ and has radius equal to $21$.If $AP=23$ and $PB=27$,then find the sum of the digits in the perimeter of the triangle $ABC$.

---

We know that inradius$=r=\frac{\Delta}{s}$,where $\Delta=$area of the triangle and $s=$semiperimeter.
Let the incircle touches side $AB$ at $P$,$BC$ at $Q$ and $AC$ at $R$
$AP=AR=23$,$PB=BQ=27$,let $CQ=CR=x$
$s=50+x$,$r=21$(given)
Using $r=\frac{\Delta}{s}$
$21=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\times50\times21+\frac{1}{2}\times(27+x)\times21+\frac{1}{2}\times(23+x)\times21}{50+x}$
But i do not get anything from this equation.

Comment: Cross multiply. It is essentially a linear equation in $x$

Comment: This converts into an identity.

Comment: Ai, that ain't cool (+1) Is it possible that both equations used to arrive at that equation are "intertwined" resulting into an identity perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula),
$$\frac{\sqrt{(100+2x)\times 2x\times 54\times 46}}{4}=21(50+x),$$
i.e.$$\sqrt{(100+2x)\times 2x\times 54\times 46}=4\times 21(50+x)$$
Squaring the both sides gives
$$(100+2x)\times 2x\times 54\times 46=4^2\times 21^2\times (50+x)^2,$$
i.e.
$$1440(x+50)(2x-245)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad x=\frac{245}{2}$$
So, 
$$AB=50,BC=299/2,CA=291/2\quad\Rightarrow\quad AB+BC+CA=345$$$$\Rightarrow\quad 3+4+5=\color{red}{12}.$$